# Linq to XML query creating empty items from XML

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-xml

Can somebody explain why is this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <item id="77" cityID="EE12345" cityDatum="15.2.2010. 11:28:35" />
</items>
```

when using query

```
Dim c = From items In st.Descendants _
             Where items.@id IsNot Nothing _
        Select New myStorage With {.id = items.@id, .cityID = items.@cityID, .cityDatum = items.@cityDatum}

storage = c.ToList
```

resulting in list(of myStorage) with two items - one with all empty (nothing) properties, second with values seen in xml above?

I've resolved the issue by adding

```
Where items.@id IsNot Nothing _
```

before Seletct New myStorage, but I have a feeling that I shouldn't be doing that.

I've recreated this in C#, storage.xml is exactly the same as specified above.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    XDocument st;
    st = XDocument.Load("C:\\storage.xml");
   Object c = from items in st.Descendants()
                    select new {id = items.Attribute("id"), cityID = items.Attribute("cityID"), cityDatum = items.Attribute("cityDatum")};
    }
```

If you, as some can't replicate these results, here's a screenshot:

[screenshot http://www.incito.hr/15.2.2010.png](http://www.incito.hr/15.2.2010.png)

Comment: I've tried this (admittedly in C#) and get only one item in `storage`, with or without the `Where` clause in place. Could you show us a short but complete program (a la http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html ) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I've expanded the question with C# example and screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it from your updated code sample. When you say

```
st = XDocument.Load("C:\\storage.xml");
```

and then

```
st.Descendants()
```

your `st` is the *document*, not the *root element*. So when you ask it for its `Descendants`, you enumerate over **2** `XElement`s - the `items` node and the one `item` node that this example have. It is the `items` node that is giving you the 'empty' item.

There are numerous ways to restrict yourself to just the `item` nodes, depending on how sure you can be about the structure of your xml - for example,

```
From item In st.Root.Elements("item")
```

will enumerate over *just* the `item` nodes found as immediate children of the document's root element.

Comment: Thanks. I must admit that an exception would have been nice because I was totally lost on this one.